# Forcing Treatment Group to Remain in Model Despite Statistical Insignificance?

Tags: sas

I am attempting to run a binary logistic regression in SAS, looking for interaction effects between the dependent variables (FRSTVACREC and CMPLTSRS), treatment groups (control vs treatment), and covariates (GENDER AGE QAGE RESP RACEETH). Covariates were identified using a correlation matrix previously. I am trying to force the treatment group variable TREAT to stay in the model despite it being statistically insignificant to see the interaction effects between TREAT and the rest of the covariates on the dependent variables. Here is my code:

```
proc logistic data=work.hpvboys_pre_analysis_final plots=(oddsratio(cldisplay=serifarrow));
  class Treat / param=glm;
  model FRSTVACREC(event='1') = Treat GENDER AGE QAGE RESP RACEETH / clparm=wald link=logit lackfit technique=fisher selection=forward slentry=0.05 sle=0.10;
run;

proc logistic data=work.hpvboys_pre_analysis_final plots=(oddsratio(cldisplay=serifarrow));
  class Treat / param=glm;
  model CMPLTSRS(event='1') = Treat GENDER AGE QAGE RESP RACEETH / clparm=wald link=logit lackfit technique=fisher selection=forward slentry=0.05 sle=0.10;
run;
```

How would I force TREAT to remain in this model?

A senior statistician recommended I use the include statement to force Treat to remain, but I do not believe the syntax allows for this. Tried forwards and backwards elimination selection, cannot figure out how to manually force it to stay.

Comment: Include - requests that the first number effects be included in every model. So that should work if you set it equal to 1 and list Treat first. Does that not work?

Comment: Wow! You are correct, I must've been misunderstanding the syntax for Include. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set INCLUDE=1 and put the variable to include as the first in the MODEL statement. Then you'll see something like the following in your output:

> The following effects will be included in each model at the top:
> Intercept TREAT